# CSS Menu doesn't dropdown when it's hovered

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, blogger

I'm having trouble with the dropdown menu of my blog. When I hover over "Plamo Reviews", it doesn't drop down the sub-menus. I read some articles related to this but still cannot find any solution. I think I did something wrong with the CSS.

Could anyone help me? 
I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

```css
nav.fixnavbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #778595;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fixednav {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 1010px;
}

.fixednav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.fixednav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fixednav li a:hover {
  background: #6c7a89;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-icon {
  display: none;
}

nav.fixnavbar.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.97;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
}

.fixednav li {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.fixednav li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class='fixnavbar'>
  <ul class='fixednav' id='togglemenu'>
    <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/list'>List bài viết</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/kinh-nghiem'>Kinh nghiệm</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/review'>Plamo Reviews</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">No1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">No2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='indzign-box' onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;indzignbox&apos;).style.top=&apos;60px&apos;;document.getElementById(&apos;count-box&apos;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;'><i class='fa fa-bars' /></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the behaviour you want, there are two things you should probably change:

1. You can get rid of the CSS rule that gives your sub-menus `li` elements a value of `display: none` as it's unnecessary. If the parent `.sub-menu` is set to `display: none` then the children will inherit that automatically.
2. You've set your `.sub-menu` to be `position: absolute`, but you haven't specified any additional CSS rules to indicate *where* it should go relative to its parent. So, for example, you can try making your `.sub-menu` rules look like the following:

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

This way, you're saying that your menu should be positioned 75 pixels beneath its parent. The `background` is just so that your sub-menu is visible against the rest of your app (you can modify this to whatever you like, of course).

Comment: @IIyaMeer Thank you for your respone! I follow your instruction and everything works well except one tiny thing. I change the sub-menu format by adding `.sub-menu li a {` but the hover area is not fill the entire button. [Image](https://imgur.com/a/bTRbjf1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Stackoverflow is a place to get your homework done. Yet, here's a working sample with the minimal fixes to make it work.

1. You were missing the position (`top`) for the `sub-menu` and it was right beneath the `fixed-nav`.
2. There was no `background-color` for the sub-menu items, so the text which is white was not visible.

```css
nav.fixnavbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #778595;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fixednav {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 1010px;
}

.fixednav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #6b7684;
}

.fixednav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fixednav li a:hover {
  background: #6c7a89;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-icon {
  display: none;
}

nav.fixnavbar.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.97;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.fixednav li {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
}

.fixednav li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class='fixnavbar'>
  <ul class='fixednav' id='togglemenu'>
    <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/list'>List bài viết</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/kinh-nghiem'>Kinh nghiệm</a></li>
    <li><a href='/search/label/review'>Plamo Reviews</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">No1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">No2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='indzign-box' onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;indzignbox&apos;).style.top=&apos;60px&apos;;document.getElementById(&apos;count-box&apos;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;'><i class='fa fa-bars' /></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```